# Mips - the user enter a capital letter and returning the number in that corresponds to that letter

Tags: assembly, mips

i have a mips code that do the opposite of what i want to do ,

this code taking a number from the user and return a letter in that corresponds index 
so help me do the opposite while i'm trying :(

```
.data
Prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter the value of n here: "
Prompt2:    .asciiz "The Letter is: "
Prompt3:    .asciiz "?\n"

.globl main
.text
main:

#print prompt 1
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt1
syscall

#get N
li  $v0, 5
syscall
blez    $v0, end
move $t8, $v0 #store N in $t8

#print prompt2
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt2
syscall

#print character equivalent
li  $v0, 4
li  $t1, '@'
add $a0, $t1, $t8
li  $v0, 11
syscall

#print ?
li  $v0, 4
la  $a0, Prompt3
syscall

end:
li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Ok, so the code you're showing is doing read number (syscall code 5) and print character (11).  You want to change those to: read character (12) and print number (1)...